# How to check if an object contains a partial key with a regex using chai js?

Tags: javascript, regex, key, chai, contain

I'm using Chai.js and I'm trying to check if an object contains a partial key. Let me explain:

I have this object to test:

```
var obj = {
    "one/two/three": "value"
}
```

And I want to check using Chai.js if the object `obj` contains a partial key `"one"` which is include in the key `"one/two/three"`.

Here I check that a key is included:

```
({ foo: 1, bar: 2 }).should.have.keys('bar');
({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }).should.include.keys('foo');
({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }).should.contain.keys('baz');
```

And here I check if a string contains a substring:

```
'foobar'.should.match(/^foo/)
```

Then, I would like to merge both to have something like this:

```
({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }).should.contain.keys.which.match('fo');
```

Do you know a way to handle this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd be very surprised if Chai has a built-in assertion for this, but its documentation does talk about how to add your own. Adding your own for the above would be fairly trivial.

Comment: I've just found docs about creating my own, looks like interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I can think of to do this is iterate over the Object's keys and check if any of them match the regular expression.

```
Object.keys({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }).some(function(key) {
    if (key.match(/^foo/) != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

You can then wrap this in some chai code to achieve the desired result like so:

```
expect(Object.keys({ foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }).some(function(key) {
    if (key.match(/^foo/) != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
})).to.equal(true);
```

In case you're unfamiliar with [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), it will immediately return true as soon as it reaches any key that causes its callback to return a truthy value.

Comment: you may have not noticed but I wanted to do this with Chai's API.